# R filter lines with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

As an example

```
df = data.frame(x=c(1,1,1,2,2),
              y=c(6,7,8,6,6))
df
```

And I want to remove this line only!

```
df %>% filter(x == 1 & y == 7)
```

So I want this output:

```
data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,2),
              y=c(6,8,6,6))
```

Does not work:

```
df %>% filter(x != 1 & y != 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Data

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    x = c(1,1,1,2,2),
    y = c(6,7,8,6,6)
  )
```

#### Code

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(!(x == 1 & y == 7))
```

#### Output

```
  x y
1 1 6
2 1 8
3 2 6
4 2 6
```